# "they ride through the main street of town" - why an article is omitted?

Tags: articles

I was reading Quentin Tarantino's DJANGO UNCHAINED screenplay and stumbled upon the following sentence:

> As the citizens of Daughtrey wake up, Django and Dr.Schultz ride Fritz and Tony through the main street of town.

Why the article before "town" is omitted? I can't find an explanation yet it does sound very natural somehow.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you!

Comment: These things are partly 'what sounds right'.  To my British ears, while 'through the centre of town' sounds fine (for a town that's been identified or at least indicated), 'through the main street of Ø town' sounds far better with a definite article than a null article at Ø. This wasn't covered exactly at the 'duplicate', but even Master didn't cover every case in depth.

Comment: Can I also point out: "Why **is** the article before "town" is omitted?"

Comment: @DJClayworth You may wisish to amend that.